# After updating the module, the payment method name has not been changed but error "The requested Payment Method is not available"

Tags: upgrade, payment-methods

After updating the payment module and making new order, I see in DB that payment method name is same as old module but old orders can not be opened. So updating sales_flat_order_payment did not help. What else I need to check? Thanks

Comment: What payment method? What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: Thanks for following up my issue. It is Klarna payment method and I upgraded to 5.3.1. I have forgotten to finish some orders before upgrade

Comment: Have you contacted Klarna?

Comment: Yes, but for incompatibility issue they do not support. In their description they have warned this incompatibility and asked to close all orders befor upgrade. Being neglect made me this trouble